# unable to parse flv and epub file contents using nutch

Tags: linux, parsing, solr, web-crawler, nutch

i am working with apache nutch and solr, my requirement is to parse the contents of flv and epub files, i am using below command to parse the files

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

i have kept the file urls in urls folder of nutch. the above command is working but when i tried to view the parsed content using solr with the following command its is just displaying the url of the files.

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

please suggest me....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second command is going to insert your crawled content into the SOLR index.

You need to run a search in SOLR to get the crawled content.
Something similar to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on
```

Can you change the "content" field in the schema.xml to stored="true", re-crawl, re-index and post the results of the SOLR search?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have already changed the content filed to store=true, but getting same result when i run a search in solar  as follows "www.epingsoft.com/epub/examples/AChristmasCarol.epub/AChristmasCarol AChristmasCarol AChristmasCarol 
www.epingsoft.com/epub/examples/AChristmasCarol.epub AChristmasCarol www.epingsoft.com/epub/examples/AChristmasCarol.epub "                please clarify one thing is it possible to get the text from flv file using nutch or not?? if not please suggest me any other tool....

Comment: In this case you will need to write your own plugin to extract and parse data from the epub files. The Tika parser does not do that, I'm afraid.